# Using 2 instances of passport-facebook strategy

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-facebook

I want to use 2 different 'passport-facebook' strategies. 
1 for login and 1 for connecting logged in user.

Obviously I register them with different names like

```
facebook    = require('passport-facebook'); ...
passport.use('facebook-login', new facebook.strategy(o, login));
passport.use('facebook-connect', new facebook.strategy(o, connect));
```

However when I call `passsport.authenticate('facebook-login',{...})(req, res, next)` from my route method `connect` is executed instead of `login`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I found the root cause.
I didn't realize named strategy is executed also during oauth callback.
And I had only 1 callback defined looking like this:

```
function fbCallback(req, res, next){
   passport.authenticate('facebook-connect', ...
```

I had to define 2nd callback and call `authenticate` method with ***facebook-login*** named strategy